# Given a distance function on the set $X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, show that it is metric and that the subset of $X$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory

> Let $X$=$\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the set of all sequences in the set $\{0,1\}$. Define a distance function on $X$ by
> $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2^n},~x\neq y \ and \ n=min\{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid x_{k} \neq y_{k} \} \\ 0,~ x=y\end{cases}$$
> where $x=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...), y=(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3},...)$
> (a) Prove that this distance function makes X into a metric space.
> (b) Prove that the set $E$ = $\{x \in X \mid x_{2}=1, x_{3}=0\}$ is open in $X$.

For (a) I am unsure how to prove the case:
For all $x,y,z \in X$ show that $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$.
I know I have to consider cases where $x=y$ and $x \neq y$. However I don't know how to apply the distance function when we have $d(x,y) = \frac{1}{2^n}$ for $x\neq y$ since $n$ is not fixed, i.e. $n=min\{k \in \mathbb{N} \mid x_{k} \neq y_{k} \}$.

For (b) I don't know how to show that the set of sequences $E$ = $\{x \in X \mid x_{2}=1, x_{3}=0\}$ is open in $X$. I don't understand how I would apply the definition of an open set to this specific set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Once you fix $x \ne y$, then $n = \min_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+} \{ k | x_k \ne y_k \}$ *is* fixed.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

1. For sequences $a$ and $b$, let $n(a,b)$ be the smallest nonnegative integer $n$ for which $x_n \neq y_n$. Then,
   $$
   n(x,y)\geq\min\{ n(x,z),n(z,y)\} .
   $$
2. Fix $x$ in $X$. If $y$ satisfies $d(x, y) < 1/2^2$, what can you say about $y$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Hint for 1. was really helpful. However, I don't understand the hint for 2. If you fix $x$ in $X$, then for some other $y$ in $X$ with $x \neq y$ we can have $d(x,y) = \frac{1}{2^1}$ if $x_{1} \neq y_{1}$. Then for any $y$ in $X$ we will have $d(x,y) \le \frac{1}{2} $. If that holds I think I should apply triangle inequality. Can you please verify if this holds? If it holds can you provide me with clues on how to apply triangle inequality?

Comment: If $d(x, y) < 1/2^2$ then $d(x, y) \leq 1/2^3$ and hence $x_k = y_k$ for $k=1, 2, 3$. But since $x$ is in $X$, it follows that $1 = x_2 = y_2$ and $0 = x_3 = y_3$ and hence $y$ is in $X$.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is this: to show that a set $X$ is [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#Metric_space), for each point $x$ in that set, you need to find *some* ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ around $x$ that is contained in $X$ (i.e., $B_\epsilon(x) \subset X$).